# Print in Android using a printer with specific IP address

Tags: java, android, sockets, printing

My query is I have a printer connected to the ethernet and I am able to print to that printer using the IP address of the printer but the issue is the printer stops the moment the lines given for printing ends and hence the paper is stuck in the printer.

My Code:

```
try {
    Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.0.131", 9100);
    PrintWriter oStream = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
    oStream.println("HI,test from Android Device");
    oStream.println("\n\n\n");
    oStream.close();
    sock.close();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: is there a way to know that if the print is successful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a `\f` at the end of the line.

```
oStream.println("\n\n\n\f");
```

It's for form feed / new page

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to print with your code after making socket connection with
    printer.

```
try {
      Socket sock = new Socket(ipAddress, 9100);
      PrintWriter oStream = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
      oStream.println("HI,test from Android Device");
      oStream.println("\n\n\n");
      oStream.close();
      sock.close();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
}
```